# Ubuntu 14.04LTS on ASUS wifi disconnecting and reconnecting

Tags: 14.04, networking, wireless, drivers, asus

Hi I'm a beginner and am currently running Ubuntu 14.04.

When I use `rfkill list` I get:

```
0: phy0: Wireless LAN 
         soft blocked: no 
         hard blocked: yes 
1: asus-wlan: wireless lan
         soft blocked: no 
         hard blocked: no
2: asus-bluetooth: bluetooth
         soft blocked: no 
         hard blocked: no
```

when I close my laptop lid and reopen it, the WiFi connects to the network and shows that it is not hard blocked any more. 
`iwconfig` gives me:

```
eth0:   no wireless extensions;
lo:     no wireless extension; 
wlan0:  IEEE 802.11bgn ESSID:"XXXXXXX" power management is off.
```

when I run `lspci -vnn | grep Network` I receive:

```
02:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Ralink corp. RT5390 wireless 802.11n 1T/1R PCIe [1814:5390]
```

will show it greyed out until I suspend or close the lid and the network is found and connected too.

*Any help or suggestions would be appreciated.*

Comment: What is the computers model number? And is asus_nb_wmi loaded `lsmod | grep asus`

Comment: Thank you. The model number is X551CA and asus_nb_wmi is loaded but shows this: asus_nb_wmi  16990  0;  asus_wmi  24191  1  asus_nb_wmi

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Good an easy fix

```
echo "options asus_nb_wmi wapf=4" | sudo tee /etc/modprobe.d/asus_nb.conf
```

Reboot and if it is still blocked try the keyboard combo to clear it

Answer (score -1):

You could try this, and enter this in the terminal:

```
 rfkill list up
 lspci wlan0
 nmcli -c -d wlan0
```

and it might work fine this way.