# Cant use WLAN of my laptop (Ubuntu 14.04)

Tags: 14.04, wireless, asus, ralink

I have an ASUS laptop of the series R704V. I installed Ubuntu 14.04 on it this Morning and Ive got a problem:
I cant use "fn + f2" to enable the WiFi. If i press "fn + f2" I get connected to the Internet but after a few seconds it turns off.
(sry for bad english)

This is the output of " lspci -knn | grep Net -A2; rfkill list"

```
03:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Ralink corp. RT5390 Wireless 802.11n 1T/1R PCIe [1814:5390]
    Subsystem: Foxconn International, Inc. Device [105b:e054]
    Kernel driver in use: rt2800pci
0: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: yes
1: asus-wlan: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A2; rfkill list` terminal command.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Ubuntu 14.04LTS on ASUS wifi disconnecting and reconnecting](http://askubuntu.com/questions/580378/ubuntu-14-04lts-on-asus-wifi-disconnecting-and-reconnecting)

Comment: the solution of the question u think, doesnt work on my laptop

Comment: Please try again that command. I fixed a typo.