# Airplane mode is enabled by hardware switch

Tags: wireless, asus, wifi-hardware-switch, airplane-mode

I'm using an Asus X550LC model. I'm facing an issue for past 6 months of wifi disabled by hard switch tried all the solution but still cannot fix it. Recently I've installed the LTS 18.04, on checking airplane mode its showing enabled by hard switch. Please if anyone knows the solution help me. I'm unable to use Ubuntu properly.

[image]

Comment: Does it change anything at all when you press the airplane mode switch? Please run the terminal command: `rfkill list all` before and after pressing the switch. Any change? Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: You should try to reset your bios somehow or click on your Airplane button during boot or like posted in here https://forums.kali.org/showthread.php?18311-WiFi-hardware-blocked-RFkill-not-working&p=26333#post26333 . Maybe by blacklisting some module (asus_wmi or asus_laptop check kernel module list at https://wiki.ubuntuusers.de/rfkill/#Kernelmodul-ist-nicht-geladen) https://ubuntu-mate.community/t/wifi-is-disabled-by-hardware-switch-hard-block-kernel/2146 or https://superuser.com/questions/819547/how-do-i-stop-rfkill-module-from-hardblocking-my-wifi-without-rfkill-command/1246511#1246511

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Ubuntu 14.04LTS on ASUS wifi disconnecting and reconnecting](https://askubuntu.com/questions/580378/ubuntu-14-04lts-on-asus-wifi-disconnecting-and-reconnecting)